# preg_match() or stripos()?

Tags: php

For doing insensitive case search in strings which function is faster preg_match() or stripos()?

```
<?php 

$string = "This is test string";    
$result = preg_match('/test/i', $string);

OR

$result = stripos($string, 'test') !== false;  
?>
```

Comment: How about benchmarking it for your particular use case?

Comment: `stripos` is way faster, but `preg_match` is much more complex.

Comment: If you aren't using regex, then don't use `preg_xxx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been my experience that stripos is much faster.

Comment: Just ran a test using your string and search... shows stripos is about 2.3x faster in that scenario to give you an example of speed difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to actually match a complex expression, or capture something then just use `stripos` or `strpos`

Answer (score 0):

strpos is faster because this function has predefine rule what this function have to do... where in preg_match function we have to pass logic from our side... so in this case first have to define rule and work based on this

so strops is faster....

Answer (score 0):

## For the real performance gain I would avoid "intensive search" at all.

Some advanced search technology, like indexed fulltext search with either mysql or sphinx, would be **a real** solution for the "intensive search" problem.

While all this negligible comparison of these **already inefficient** functions involving full scan of data won't help.

If you insists on using those - no performance being your concern. Thus - do not waste anyone's time with comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`stripos` is slow, better than use `strtolower` than `strpos`

```
<?php

function loop()
{
  $str_50 = str_repeat('a', 50).str_repeat('b', 50);
  $str_100 = str_repeat('a', 100).str_repeat('b', 100);
  $str_500 = str_repeat('a', 250).str_repeat('b', 250);
  $str_1k = str_repeat('a', 1024).str_repeat('b', 1024);
  $str_10k = str_repeat('a', 10240).str_repeat('b', 1024);
  $str_100k = str_repeat('a', 102400).str_repeat('b', 1024);
  $needle = 'b';

  header("Content-Type: text/plain");

  echo str_replace(',', "\t", 'count,strpos,preg,stripos,preg i,strpos(tolower)').PHP_EOL;

  foreach(array($str_50, $str_100, $str_500, $str_1k, $str_10k, $str_100k) as $str)
  {
    echo strlen($str);
    $start = mt();
    for($i = 0; $i < 25000; $i++) $j = strpos($str, $needle); // strpos
    echo "\t".mt($start);

    $regex = '!'.$needle.'!';
    $start = mt();
    for($i = 0; $i < 25000; $i++) $j = preg_match($regex, $str); // preg
    echo "\t".mt($start);

    $start = mt();
    for($i = 0; $i < 25000; $i++) $j = stripos($str, $needle); // stripos
    echo "\t".mt($start);

    $regex = '!'.$needle.'!i';
    $start = mt();
    for($i = 0; $i < 25000; $i++) $j = preg_match($regex, $str); // preg i
    echo "\t".mt($start);

    $str = strtolower($str);
    $start = mt();
    for($i = 0; $i < 25000; $i++) $j = strpos($str, $needle); // strtolower strpos
    echo "\t".mt($start);

    echo PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo PHP_EOL;
}


function mt($start = null)
{
  if($start === null)
    return microtime(true);
  return number_format(microtime(true)-$start, 4);
}


loop();
```

Result in seconds

```
count       strpos      preg        stripos     preg i      strpos(tolower)
 100        0.0243      0.0395      0.0878      0.0339      0.0094
 200        0.0100      0.0334      0.1636      0.0354      0.0103
 500        0.0114      0.0368      0.4211      0.0415      0.0115
2048        0.0174      0.0556      1.5797      0.0653      0.0171
11264       0.0896      0.2727      8.7098      0.3531      0.0890
103424      0.8218      2.4429      79.7007     3.2986      0.8190
```